# Remove headers from a fasta file

Tags: regex, string, bioinformatics, fasta

I have cDNA.fa file in fasta format and I want to remove all fasta headers except the ENST name (transcript id). How can I remove them? I don't want to lose any cDNA sequence. Thanks in advance.

```
>ENST00000390567.1 cdna chromosome:GRCh38:14:105881034:105881053:-1 gene:ENSG00000211907.1 gene_biotype:IG_D_gene transcript_biotype:IG_D_gene gene_symbol:IGHD1-26 description:immunoglobulin heavy diversity 1-26 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:5485]
GGTATAGTGGGAGCTACTAC
>ENST00000452198.1 cdna chromosome:GRCh38:14:105881539:105881556:-1 gene:ENSG00000225825.1 gene_biotype:IG_D_gene transcript_biotype:IG_D_gene gene_symbol:IGHD6-25 description:immunoglobulin heavy diversity 6-25 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:5516]
GGGTATAGCAGCGGCTAC
>ENST00000390569.1 cdna chromosome:GRCh38:14:105883903:105883922:-1 gene:ENSG00000211909.1 gene_biotype:IG_D_gene transcript_biotype:IG_D_gene gene_symbol:IGHD5-24 description:immunoglobulin heavy diversity 5-24 (non-functional) [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:5510]
GTAGAGATGGCTACAATTAC
>ENST00000437320.1 cdna chromosome:GRCh38:14:105884870:105884888:-1 gene:ENSG00000227196.1 gene_biotype:IG_D_gene transcript_biotype:IG_D_gene gene_symbol:IGHD4-23 description:immunoglobulin heavy diversity 4-23 (non-functional) [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:5504]
TGACTACGGTGGTAACTCC
>ENST00000390571.1 cdna chromosome:GRCh38:14:105886031:105886061:-1 gene:ENSG00000211911.1 gene_biotype:IG_D_gene transcript_biotype:IG_D_gene gene_symbol:IGHD3-22 description:immunoglobulin heavy diversity 3-22 [Source:HGNC Symbol;Acc:HGNC:5497]
GTATTACTATGATAGTAGTGGTTATTACTAC
```

I want my file to look like this:

```
>ENST00000390567.1 
GGTATAGTGGGAGCTACTAC
>ENST00000452198.1 
GGGTATAGCAGCGGCTAC
```

Answer (score 3):

Use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -lpe 's/^(>\S+).*/$1/' input.fa > output.fa
```

The Perl one-liner uses these command line flags:
`-e` : Tells Perl to look for code in-line, instead of in a file.
`-p` : Loop over the input one line at a time, assigning it to `$_` by default. Add `print $_` after each loop iteration.
`-l` : Strip the input line separator (`"\n"` on *NIX by default) before executing the code in-line, and append it when printing.

`s/^(>\S+).*/$1/` : In this substitution, `^` is the beginning of the line, `>` is the literal `>`, which marks the fasta header, `\S+` is non-whitespace character repeated 1 or more times, and `.*` is any character repeated 0 or more times (which matches the entire line starting from the first whitespace character onward). By adding the parenthesis, `(>\S+)` captures what you need into the first capture variable, `$1`, which we then use to replace the entire line.

**SEE ALSO:**
[`perldoc perlrun`: how to execute the Perl interpreter: command line switches](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes)](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
[`perldoc perlre`: Perl regular expressions (regexes): Quantifiers; Character Classes and other Special Escapes; Assertions; Capture groups](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions)
[`perldoc perlrequick`: Perl regular expressions quick start](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick)

Answer (score 2):

There's a great answer for Perl, but if you more Python inclined you might want to try `Bioython`.

Based on your question, a `sample.fasta` file can be parsed with this:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

for seq_record in SeqIO.parse("sample.fa", "fasta"):
    print(seq_record.id)
    print(str(seq_record.seq))
```

Output:

```
ENST00000390567.1
GGTATAGTGGGAGCTACTAC
ENST00000452198.1
GGGTATAGCAGCGGCTAC
ENST00000390569.1
GTAGAGATGGCTACAATTAC
ENST00000437320.1
TGACTACGGTGGTAACTCC
ENST00000390571.1
GTATTACTATGATAGTAGTGGTTATTACTAC
```

And if you want to write this back to a file:

```
from Bio import SeqIO

lines = [[sq_rec.id, sq_rec.seq] for sq_rec in SeqIO.parse("sample.fa", "fasta")]
with open("out.fa", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write('\n'.join(f"{id_}\n{seq}" for id_, seq in lines) + "\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

More simply, just using bash `cut` (your data are in `seqs.fa`):

```
$ cut -f 1 -d" " seqs.fa 
>ENST00000390567.1
GGTATAGTGGGAGCTACTAC
>ENST00000452198.1
GGGTATAGCAGCGGCTAC
>ENST00000390569.1
GTAGAGATGGCTACAATTAC
>ENST00000437320.1
TGACTACGGTGGTAACTCC
>ENST00000390571.1
GTATTACTATGATAGTAGTGGTTATTACTAC
```

Answer (score 2):

Fasta files are often quickly processed with awk. They even designed a special awk, ie bioawk, to process fasta files.

In standard awk, you can do:

```
awk '/>/{$0=$1}1' file.fasta
```

In bioawk it's a bit more convoluted to do these simple tasks

```
bioawk -c fastx '{sub(/ */,"",$name}{ print ">"$name ORS $seq }' file.fasta
```

**Note:** [BioAwk](https://github.com/lh3/bioawk) is based on [Brian Kernighan's awk](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/%7Ebwk/btl.mirror/) which is documented in ["The AWK Programming Language",
by Al Aho, Brian Kernighan, and Peter Weinberger
(Addison-Wesley, 1988, ISBN 0-201-07981-X)](https://ia802309.us.archive.org/25/items/pdfy-MgN0H1joIoDVoIC7/The_AWK_Programming_Language.pdf)
. I'm not sure if this version is compatible with [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/ut).